# Create method / function that can be reuse in a JS class.

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I got error of `React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined.`

I want to have a public method within a class because I want to reuse that function in other method,what's wrong with my code below?

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.getCurrentMonthData('2017-10-1', '2017-12-1'); 
}
getCurrentMonthData = (from, to) => {
    //do something
}
OtherFunc = () => {
   this.getCurrentMonthData('2017-10-1', '2017-12-1');  
}
```

Comment: Is that within the class body or the constructor?

Comment: The problem exists in your render function. Either you have not written render function or it is not returning anything.

Answer (score 0):

```
import {Your_Component_Name} from '../components/xyz.js';
```

vs

```
import Your_Component_Name from '../components/xyz.js';
```

In my case the second one works while the first caused the error.

try importing your component like this.